# Connecting to a Cassandra Docker Container Using Cassandra Spring Data

Tags: cassandra, spring-data

So I am running in to issues connecting to a single node cassandra cluster using spring data-cassandra. I am using the docker image found at: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/

using a docker-compose with the following environment variables set:

```
cassandra_n1:
  image: cassandra:latest
  ports:
    - "9042:9042"
    - "9160:9160"
  hostname: cassandra_n1
  environment:
    CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: "mycluster"
    CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH: "PropertyFileSnitch"
    CASSANDRA_DC: "DC1"
    CASSANDRA_RACK: "R1"
```

then after this starts I try to connect to it using my spring boot application which is as simple as:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MvcApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MvcApplication.class);
        }
    }
```

which scans for a configuration file which is:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "myproject.repository" })
public class CassandraConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {

        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("cassandra.port")));

        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(env.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
        session.setConverter(converter());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }
}
```

that looks at the property file cassandra.properties which is:

```
cassandra.contactpoints=192.168.99.100
cassandra.port=9042
cassandra.keyspace=mykeyspace
```

I am using docker-machine as a docker daemon which has a address of 192.168.99.100

in my pom i'm using the dependencies:

```
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

After i build and run my application, the application fails to connect to cassandra showing a message:

```
 Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:
 All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.99.100:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException: 
[/192.168.99.100:9042] Unexpected error during transport initialization (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: 
[/192.168.99.100:9042] Unexpected exception triggered (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Not enough readable bytes - Need 4, maximum is 0))))
```

I have tried to set the listen_address, broadcast_address and the rpc_address to the docker daemon ip but have not had success.
Any help would be appriciated

Comment: in case anyone comes across this in their searching I was using the wrong version of spring-data, and once i changed the pom things went somewhat smoother

Comment: I am getting same issue in my service if I deploy it in `pcf` working fine but using `docker container` getting this issue, and able to connect from local from my service ... I am using 
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>`
please let me know which version fixed the issue for you. Thanks.

Comment: i was using 1.3.2.RELEASE but that was a while ago, with cassandra version updates and the data dependency updates, it could be very much different now. worth a shot though